# Is there something like @MappedSuperclass for OrientDB?

Tags: java, orientdb

I want to create an `AbstractEntity` class for `id` & `version` fields, so I don't have to declare those fields & accessors in every entity class. Something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id private Object id;
    @Version private Integer version;

    public Object getId() { return id; }
    (...)

public class User extends AbstractEntity {
    private String login;
    private String password;
    (...)
```

In JPA, I could annotate `AbstractEntity` with `@MappedSuperclass`, so it won't generate an `AbstractEntity` table on db. How can I achieve the same behavior in OrientDB Object Database API? I don't want an `AbstractEntity` class in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today there isn't an annotation for that but you've to declare the class as "Abstract" in the schema. Example:

```
OClass abstractEntity = db.getMetadata().getSchema().createClass("AbstractEntity");
abstractEntity.setAbstract( true );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try this.